# java.io.EOFException at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint (tomcat 9 & openjdk 8)

Tags: java, java-8, http2, tomcat9, eofexception

I am upgrading the tomcat and openjdk version for a project. Target: Tomcat 9.0.63 and openjdk-8u322-b06.

However, getting EOFException when using Tomcat 9.0.63 and openjdk-8u322-b06.

I don't know how to fix it.

### Findings:

**Error occurs** if using Tomcat 9.0.**63** and openjdk-8u**252**-b09 **or later version**.

**No errors** occurs if using Tomcat 9.0.**35** and openjdk-8u**322**-b06.

**No errors** occurs if using Tomcat 9.0.**63** and openjdk-8u**242**-b08 **or previous version**.

```
[https-jsse-nio-443-exec-2] org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2AsyncParser$FrameCompletionHandler.failed Connection [1], Stream [0], Frame type [null], Error
    java.io.EOFException
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper$NioOperationState.run(NioEndpoint.java:1659)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase$OperationState.start(SocketWrapperBase.java:1068)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.vectoredOperation(SocketWrapperBase.java:1487)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.read(SocketWrapperBase.java:1330)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.read(SocketWrapperBase.java:1302)
            at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2AsyncParser.readConnectionPreface(Http2AsyncParser.java:55)
            at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.init(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:253)
            at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2AsyncUpgradeHandler.init(Http2AsyncUpgradeHandler.java:41)
            at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2UpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(Http2UpgradeHandler.java:328)
            at org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2AsyncUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(Http2AsyncUpgradeHandler.java:41)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:60)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Tomcat server.xml

```
    <Connector port="9443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
           ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
           keystoreFile="path" keystorePass="xxxx">
       <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
</Connector>
```

port 443

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
           ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
           keystoreFile="path" keystorePass="xxxx">
           <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
</Connector>
```

port 8080

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="9443"
       useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />

<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="443"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Tomcat 9.0.36+ and openjdk 8_252+ not support http2 and NioProtocol at the same time. It must be use apr protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol" and change the server.xml

```
<Connector port="9443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
           maxThreads="150"
           compression="on" compressionMinSize="2048"
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.1" certificateVerification="none">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="xxx.keystore"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="xxx"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

If using protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol", it needs to remove `<UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />`, no error occurs but http1.1 only.

Comment: In addition, tomcat-native must be use. After yum install apr-devel openssl-devel, please download the lastest tomcat-native from apache. If the tomcat-native is not lastest version. It causes Failed to initialize the SSLEngine. org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 70023: This function has not been implemented on this platform at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL.initialize.